# Stream - Merge similar events data into one event

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I would like to merge the incoming events into one event based on one of the fields.

Input Events:

```
{
  ID: '123',
  eventType: 'a',
  eventCode: 1
},
{
  ID: '123',
  eventType: 'b',
  eventCode: 2
},
{
  ID: '123',
  eventType: 'c',
  eventCode: 3
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  ID: '123',
  events: [{
    eventType: 'a',
    eventCode: 1
  },
  {
    eventType: 'b',
    eventCode: 2
  },
  {
    eventType: 'c',
    eventCode: 3
  }]
}
```

I am grouping the events based on a window of 4. So, I need to process the 4 events, merge them and pass it onto the next step.

**Use Case**:
I would like to use the generated output to be stored in MongoDB OR pass it onto an external service.

Is this possible using Siddhi?

**NOTE**: I see that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152289/wso2-cep-multiple-rows-in-resultset) has already been asked, but the response is from 5 years ago, and Siddhi has come long way since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below Siddhi apps to achieve your requirement. I have utilized [string extension](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-execution-string) to do this. But please note generated output is exactly the one you requested. If you want a proper JSON output you might have to utilize [execution json extention](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-execution-json) as well. Follow the readme for details on extension usage.

```
@App:name("testJsonConcat")
@App:description("Description of the plan")

-- Please refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Quick+Start+Guide on getting started with SP editor. 

define stream inputStream(id string, eventType string, eventCode int);

partition with (id of inputStream)
begin
from inputStream
select id, str:concat("{eventType: '", eventType, "' , eventCode :",eventCode,"}") as jsonString
insert into #formattedStream;

from #formattedStream#window.lengthBatch(4)
select str:concat("{ ID : '", id, "',events: [", str:groupConcat(jsonString),"]}") as result
insert into concatStream;
end;

from concatStream#log()
select *
insert into temp;
```

Comment: Superb. I was trying something similar with `eventWindow` and stuff, but I had no idea how to use partitions. This solution did not only worked out perfectly fine for me, but it also taught me few new things! As per your suggestion, I have used `json:toObject` and got myself exactly what I wanted.